# Changing checkbox to checked clicking on span does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to develop a toggle button with a checkbox using css and jquery. I want to click on the span, which represents my toggle button, to change the property checked of the given checkbox. 
Unfortunately the span does not change the property. However it goes into the right jQuery function. Using the button, it is going into the function and changing the property. Can you tell me why I cannot use the span to change the property?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".taskcomplete2", function() {
  if ($(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked')) {
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger taskcomplete2">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the click event to the span as well

```
$(document).on("click",".taskcomplete2,.taskcompletecheck", function(){

    ....
});
```

```js
$(document).on("click",".taskcomplete2,.taskcompletecheck", function(){
  if($(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked')){
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', false);
  }else{
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger taskcomplete2">Button</button>
```

Comment: I’m curious why this is necessary - without any JS at all, the slider functions correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's working now! But why do I have to do this? I added the event to the span, but why do I have to add this also to the checkbox?

Comment: Click event fires multiple times.

Comment: You need to add it to whatever element you interact with. In your case, you only added the event to the button, not to the checkbox or the span. @DS87

Comment: @SumeshTG maybe because other answers also attach the same event to the same class

Comment: @Ahmad check my answer.

Comment: @Ahmad: I added it to both. The nested span has the taskcomplete2 class and the button. I tried it out with and without the button. Or do I missunderstand you?

Comment: @DS87 In your original question, the `.on('click',)` was only triggered by `.taskcomplete2` . You forgot to also attach it to `.taskcomplete`

Answer (score 0):

JS could be not necessary at all, if you set the `for` attribute on the labels and the `id` on the input

```
<label class="switch" for="taskcomplete">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck" id="taskcomplete">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
```

So since the `span` element is nested into the `label`, if you click it then the checkbox will be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply, [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes) attribute to get button click to work, however Please use `e.preventDefault();`

```
<label for="buttonToggle" class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
<button type="button" id="buttonToggle" class="btn btn-danger taskcomplete2">Button</button>
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).on("click",".taskcomplete2", function(e){

      if($(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked')){
        $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', false);
      }else{
        $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', true);
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 34px;
    }
    
    /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
    .switch input {
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    /* The slider */
    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }
    
    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
      transform: translateX(26px);
    }
    
    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }
    
    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="buttonToggle" class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
<button type="button" id="buttonToggle" class="btn btn-danger taskcomplete2">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".switch", function(e) {

  if ($(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked')) {
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked', true);
  }
  console.log("Status :: "+$(".taskcompletecheck").prop('checked'));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="taskcompletecheck">
   <span class="slider round taskcomplete2"></span>
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger taskcomplete2">Button</button>
```

Apply event on parent element.